# Is it normal to have a performance problem in Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it normal to have a performance problem in doctrine when working with insert or update of more than 2000 records? Should I turn to the PDO?

Comment: Doctrine is a wrapper for PDO(and others too). Most likely it boils down to your queries. Granted Doctrine does add some overhead but usually it's negligible. Post some code too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Doctrine is effective when you use bulk selects, but very bad if you use bulk update, insert or delete. Do not use doctrine for those operations use plain sql.
When you bulk insert for example, you create 2000 objects (poor server memory) and then doctrine insert it one by one if you do flush in a loop. Of course you can persist them for example with 200 object chunk and flush, but still memory usage will be a lot bigger than inserting via plain sql.
Even worse if you select 2000 records with doctrine then those records become not only entity objects, but they become persistent collection with a lot of other objects mapped to them and when you try to persist them server will use even more memory.